# Can a dumb component use/render redux container component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the [getting started](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-extracting-container-components-filterlink#/guidelinesModal) video of Redux we see that the Footer (a dumb component) uses Filterlink (a container).

But when I read this [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.49376my94), it seems, but not very clearly, that only containers should use/render containers.

For me, if Footer uses Filterlink (which is tied to Redux) I can't reuse it on other projects which don't use Redux. But maybe it is an exception? Maybe hard coding dumb component for use only on one project is ok?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The article was somewhat out of date with how I think about it today. I just updated it so you can [read it again with the fresh perspective](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.49376my94). I’ve come to the opinion that it’s totally fine to use container components inside presentational components. The reason for this is simple: you want to be able to turn a presentational component into a container component at any time it needs too much information, and it would be a bummer if you had to convert all call sites when you do that. Therefore whether a component is presentational or a container is its implementation detail, and any components, whether presentational or containers, can use it just fine.

Comment: We need a new article Dan!

Comment: Need a new article +1

Comment: TBH, I am upvoting this not only because I agree with it but also because Grandmaster Dan replied 11 minutes after the question was made. That my friends, is wizard-level techniques.

Comment: Is there any for Angular? I am looking for a boilerplate with reusable form and lists? Any suggetion please?