# Redux - Component different approaches (Smart / Dumb / Container / Presentation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So, I know that there is no one 'correct' approach to this, but I wanted to have a conversation about the pros and cons of each approach.

So, After reading Dan Abramov's [post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.2nt6eqfuw) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992473/916450), and going over [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) tutorial, I wonder the pros and cons for those two different approaches:

Approach A:

```
├── Smart / Container component
│   ├── Dumb / presentation component
│   │   ├── Dumb / presentation component
│   ├── Dumb / presentation component
```

Aproach B:

```
├── Smart / Container component
│   ├── Dumb / presentation component
│   │   ├── Smart / Container component
│   ├── Dumb / presentation component
```

The main difference here is how you manage your state. In option B the deepest component should be aware of redux (dispach, for example), which can be a disadvantage. In approach A you might need to pass props down the tree between many Dumb components.

**EDIT**

A strange thing is that in [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html), on "Passing the Store" section, you can find a reference to the "[magic](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)" behind "Provider" (react context). In context docs it is clearly says:

> Just as global variables are best avoided when writing clear code, you
>   should avoid using context in most cases

and:

> Before you build components with this API, consider if there are
>   cleaner alternatives. We're fond of simply passing the items as an
>   array in cases like this

So, as far as I can understand it is some kind of bad practice?? (Option B...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes a question of readability and re-rendering performance.  Sometimes it may be more readable to explicitly pass down props through a couple levels.  Other times it may be easier to understand if you start a new connection and pull in the data you need right there.  Also, note that `connect()` does a *lot* of work to make sure that your own component only re-renders when it really has to, so you can actually get some potential performance improvements when a component is connected.  In contrast, "dumb" components often do not implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, meaning they will re-render every time.

As you said, there is no single right answer - use `connect()` wherever it makes sense for your own application structure.

edit:

To answer your question about the React Context docs, React-Redux's `<Provider>` component specifically encapsulates the fact that it happens to use Context.  That way, if there *are* any changes to the Context API or behavior in the future, your own app shouldn't have to worry about it, as it can be taken care of by updates to Provider.

In other words, don't worry about it :)